# Add my footer menu to the header

Tags: php, css, headers, footer

I want to add more links in my menu.

duvacon.de ---> you see only the "categories", I want also add the links of my footer menu to the header.

This code is for the header menu, now I want to add a link for "contact", "chat"... in the header

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="btn"><?php _e("Categories", "myfriv"); ?> <span class="icon icon-angle-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="actions">
      <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more links in your header menu like:

```
<div class="menu">
  <a class="btn">Kategorien <span class="icon icon-angle-down"></span></a>
     <ul class="actions"><!--THIS IS YOUR CATEGORIES SUBMENU-->
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-17">
          <a href="https://duvacon.de/category/action/" data-hasqtip="13" oldtitle="Action" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-13">Action</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- NEW ITEMS -->
  <a href="%LINKTOCONTACT%" class="btn">Contact</a>
  <a href="%LINKTOCHAT%" class="btn">Chat</a>
</div>
```

I don't know if you are adding in the wordpress backend menu, but if yes you can maybe use [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). I think it is more easy to create menus and manage them.

Comment: hello dont work, they have all the submenü.

Comment: edit your question and share your whole code, and how you are displaying the others menu items

Answer (score 0):

i can do it like this example

```
<div class="menu">
        <a href="link" class="btn">Chat<span class="icon icon-angle-down"></span></a>
        </div>


        <div class="menu">
        <a href="link" class="btn">Spiel hinzfügen?<span class="icon icon-angle-down"></span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
        <a href="link" class="btn">Kontakt<span class="icon icon-angle-down"></span></a>
        </div>
```